# Does standard library refer to the whole API or just a package?

Tags: standard-library, java

When the term "standard library" is used, is that referring to the collection of packages provided for the Java language, defined in the Java API?  Or is the Java API documenting the collection of packages offered in the Java language, each of which is a standard library?  I've found a lot of sources online that seem to use the term "standard library" ambiguously and I want to make sure I have the right definition.

**EDIT**

The link proposed to answer this question does not discuss the definition of standard libraries at all.     If my question as phrased is ambiguous I can rewrite to clarify whatever is confusing, but it certainly has not been already answered.

Comment: The Java Standard Library refers to the collection of classes provided by the Java language.

Comment: @Braj: That's something entirely different and unrelated.

Comment: from my understanding of your question, its both.

Comment: That question does not address what I am asking.